# ChtmlView MFC memory leaks on javascript

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an MFC application which needs to display a webpage.  I've added a CHtmlView through CSingleDocTemplate which spawns a window and displays the page fine but it leaks memory when running javascript.

The page I'm looking at is genereated by Madcap flare and so it very heavy with javascript.  I'm losing about 4K a second just sitting watching the page.

I've tried to reduce the problem by letting the user close the document but then I run into a problem with not knowing if the CFrameWnd was closed or not in the main application so not knowing if I need to create a new one or just reuse it.

I'm running this on windows 7 with IE9 installed so if I'm right I should be well clear of the old IE javascript circular references bug.

Comment: I believe you shouldn't bother about it, specially if you have not allocated any memory yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it happen in both Release and Debug build? I've seen similar (somewhat deterministic) errors when **freeing dangling pointers** or blowing the stack. With a bit of bad luck, the *undefined behavior* from faulty code could produce memory leaks.

1. Try enabling all possible runtime checks in your build and see if the error goes away (or is somehow detected).
2. Try commenting out large code blocks and see if the error goes away.

I'm just guessing here :)

Comment: It seems to be driven by bad javascript from MadCap.  The memory does level off after a while.  Hopefully it's nothing to worry about.